# TextEdit setText("some text here") changes my text color to white

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I call `usernameField.setText(myEmail)` it changes the text to white. The email address is still in there but it seems to be hidden for some reason. What could be causing this?

```
usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextField);
usernameField.setText(myEmail);
usernameField.setTextColor(color.black);
```

XML for whole view:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usernameTextField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/emailHint"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:textColorLink="@color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordtextField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameTextField"
    android:layout_below="@+id/usernameTextField"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword|textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/emailHint"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:textColorLink="@color/black" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageButton    
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:src="@drawable/wallet_menu_profile" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/loginHint"
    />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:text="@string/prowdstatus"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/grey" />
```

Comment: plese, add code from xml (for your view)

Comment: I have added the XML for the code now.

Comment: have you tried `usernameField.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);`
the C is capital in `Color.BLACK` and black too.!

Comment: that was the answer. Please post it as an answer Ankxx and Ill set it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the possible culprit: android:textColorLink="@color/white"

Change it to black or remove it and you're set.

Answer (score 2):

you use

```
android:textColorLink="@color/white"
```

change this color for black or other, or remove this line from xml beacuse if you set the email in editText android can change color for white and create link. (not sure if this happen by default, but if you add 
android:autoLink="for example email", and if the text will be hosted email - text changed color automatically and created link.

I hope this will help you.